# How can I get ASP Application variables with C# HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, asp-classic, httprequest

I have 2 Applications, one in Classic ASP and other in C#. I want to get the Applications variables of ASP in my C# Application in a synchronized way, with HttpRequest. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just copy from your global.asa to your global.asax?

Comment: Actually, I am using the Application variable dynamically, so I have to check their current content. I can't just copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a classic asp script which writes out the requested application variable. consider security things.

example:

```
if session("isLoggedInOrSomething") = true then
    if request.form("act") = "gimmeAppVar" then
        response.write application( request.form("requestedAppVar") )
    end if
end if
```

now call that .asp page from your c# by HttpRequest and post the needed parameters...